# I am having trouble to solver the error "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'byte[]

Tags: java, android

> Error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.fadhil.ppmproject, PID: 17263
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'byte[] java.lang.String.getBytes()' on a null object reference
        at android.util.Base64.decode(Base64.java:119)
        at com.fadhil.ppmproject.adapters.UsersAdapter.getUserImage(UsersAdapter.java:65)
        at com.fadhil.ppmproject.adapters.UsersAdapter.access$000(UsersAdapter.java:19)
        at com.fadhil.ppmproject.adapters.UsersAdapter$UserViewHolder.setUserData(UsersAdapter.java:58)
        at com.fadhil.ppmproject.adapters.UsersAdapter.onBindViewHolder(UsersAdapter.java:39)
        at com.fadhil.ppmproject.adapters.UsersAdapter.onBindViewHolder(UsersAdapter.java:19)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7065)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7107)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6012)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6279)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1627)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3851)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4404)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21912)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21912)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1873)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21912)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21912)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21912)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21912)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21912)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:779)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:21912)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6260)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:3080)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2590)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1721)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7598)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:966)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:790)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:725)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:951)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

> Adapter.java

```
package com.fadhil.ppmproject.adapters;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.fadhil.ppmproject.databinding.ItemContainerUserBinding;
import com.fadhil.ppmproject.models.User;

import java.util.List;

public class UsersAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UsersAdapter.UserViewHolder> {
    private final List<User> users;

    public UsersAdapter(List<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public UserViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        ItemContainerUserBinding itemContainerUserBinding = ItemContainerUserBinding.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()),
                parent,
                false
        );
        return new UserViewHolder(itemContainerUserBinding);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UsersAdapter.UserViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.setUserData(users.get(position));

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return users.size();
    }

    public class UserViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ItemContainerUserBinding binding;

        UserViewHolder (ItemContainerUserBinding itemContainerUserBinding){
            super(itemContainerUserBinding.getRoot());
            binding = itemContainerUserBinding;
        }
        void  setUserData(User user){
            binding.textName.setText(user.name);
            binding.textEmail.setText(user.email);
            binding.imageProfile.setImageBitmap(getUserImage(user.image));
        }

    }

    private Bitmap getUserImage(String encodedImage){

        byte[] bytes = Base64.decode(encodedImage,Base64.DEFAULT);
       return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes,0,bytes.length);
    }
}
```

Comment: `user.image` is null.

Comment: so what should i do to fix it?

Comment: I can't see from the given code snippet where it's coming from. Check for null, or make it not be null.

Answer (score 0):

Jus check if the user image :

```
if(user.image!=null){
binding.imageProfile.setImageBitmap(getUserImage(user.image)
}
```